# Fatal error occurs when container views are added to code

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, fatal-error, uicontainerview

I realize similar question about fatal errors and unwrapping optionals have been asked, but in this case the only things I have added to my code are two outlets (I've checked their connections) and now I am experiencing errors in places that previously didn't set off errors.

My code was running well and then I added two container views and it crashes saying: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value," but I can't figure out where the optional could be. It says it has to do with a UIview called segmentBackground but that didn't set off any error before I added the container views.

Thank you for your help in advanced.

Here is my code:

```
class DetailMosaicViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// Properties
var mosaic: String?
var overviewBottomBorder: UIView?
var modelsBottomBorder: UIView?
var sectionTitles = [String]() {
    didSet {
        profileTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
var mainText = [String]() {
    didSet {
        profileTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var segmentBackground: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var profileModelsSegment: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var modelsContainerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var profileContainerView: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let mosaic = mosaic {
        navigationItem.title = mosaic
    }
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0)
    configureSegmentController()
    configureText()
    // Configures TableView
    profileTableView.delegate = self
    profileTableView.dataSource = self
    profileTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.black
    profileTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    profileTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func configureSegmentController() {
    segmentBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0)
    profileModelsSegment.center = segmentBackground.center
    profileModelsSegment.setTitle("Profile", forSegmentAt: 0)
    profileModelsSegment.setTitle("Models", forSegmentAt: 1)
    profileModelsSegment.tintColor = UIColor.white
    profileModelsSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}

func configureText() {
    // make request to firebase, store, and assign to tableView
    sectionTitles = ["Description", "Business Models", "Moats", "Competition", "Unit Economics"]
}

@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.profileTableView.alpha = 1
            self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.profileTableView.alpha = 0
            self.modelsContainerView.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}

// TableView Datasource
// Customizes Section Titles
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Makes Background White
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customHeader") as UITableViewCell!
    cell?.textLabel?.text = sectionTitles[section]
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //configure cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCell

    cell.mainSectionText.text = "Box (company) Box (formerly Box.net), based in Redwood City, California, is a cloud content management and file sharing service for businesses. The company uses a freemium business model to provide cloud storage and file hosting for personal accounts and businesses."

    return cell
}
```

}

And this is the error message:

[image: Error Message]

My outlet connection:

[image: connection]

Comment: Not marking as a duplicate because I don't know enough Swift to tell, but take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/1586231) answer and see if it answers your question.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Max. I was looking at that question, but I still couldn't see where the optional unwrapping manifested in my code. Especially if the elements causing an error didn't cause an error prior to adding the container views.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your `segmentBackground` before you can update a property. Something like `segmentBackground = UIView()` will suffice.

If you are connecting a `UIView` from a storyboard, make sure the connection is valid. In Xcode, this can be done by viewing the Connections Inspector and ensuring the correct connection has been configured:

[image]

Comment: I tried disconnecting the UIView and reconnecting it from the storyboard and it still didn't work.

Comment: @BenNalle maybe attach a screenshot of your connection in the storyboard to your question?

Comment: I added one. It looks identical to the picture you've included.

Comment: As you have been adding/removing views make sure there it not a segmentBackground connection to another object in the view